# Detect when an AJAX request starts

Tags: javascript, ajax

Following the spec I've been given for this particular item, I have a few dozen AJAX requests all initiated at the same time, and the results displayed as they complete to give responses as soon as possible.

Currently I have all of the items show as "Loading...", then gradually getting replaced as the requests complete.

Due to limitations placed by the browser, only about five of them *actually* load at any given time, the others are blocked until earlier ones have completed.

I'd like to know if there's any way of finding out when the block ends and the request is actually sent.

Initial tests using `onreadystatechange` to detect `readyState` values other than `4` are not promising - no event is fired until it's complete, at which point I get `2`, `3` and `4` in immediate succession (note that for testing, the AJAX responses are artificially delayed by `usleep`ing for a random time)

Any ideas? Or is my only real option to manually implement the blocking part?

Comment: You mean it is the browser doing the blocking; you throw 10 requests into the wild and the browser will only allow 5 of them to be invoked in parallel and the rest are put on hold. If you don't get any relevant answers, you may have to create a queue yourself so you yourself do the starting of requests at an appropriate time. As a last resort solution.

Comment: Can you verify (via your network monitor) that the responses are actually being delayed significantly enough to make each `readyState` transition distinct?

Comment: @svidgen : I have tested this point by hitting a ajax target with a sleep of 6 secs. As mentioned 2,3,4 triggered continuously after 6 secs. Here is [a demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2nWCq/).

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but I trigger a custom event in the `beforeSend` state and then another one in the `success` state and I can trigger other functions throughout my code using those.

Comment: Can you please post your code for us to try out?

Comment: What browser are you using? and yes with the source code it would be much easier to investigate your problem.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni It applies to all browsers.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol OK,... and can you give us some source code, it would be a good starting point for further investigations.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni A really simple test would be to choose your preferred AJAX request syntax, and call a PHP script that's just `<?php sleep(5); echo 'Hi'; ?>` - fire off a hundred simultaneous AJAX requests and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

The best approximation of this you can actually get is to watch for readyState "1".. which signifies the server connection has been established. This will give you a *pretty close* estimation as to when the connection actually went live.

I've hacked up at http://jsfiddle.net/r0gknr3w/. Just watch the JS console, and you'll see "1" logged. You say you never saw a readyState 1... but it's definitely there.

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    url: "/echo/html",
    xhr: function () {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            console.log(xhr.readyState);
        }
        return xhr;

    }
});
```

Comment: Hm, interesting... I'm only getting `1` logged... and I'm getting it twice. When I ran my tests, I did see `1` appear logged when in IE only, Chrome skipped over it entirely. Also, when the response is delayed, the `1` is logged immediately in IE, followed by the lock wait, then `234` in immediate succession.

Comment: I'm seeing "1,2,4" in succession every time.

Answer (score -3):

Can you use jquery function to call ajax request.It is better to send multiple request parallel and response get as soon as..

Comment: Impossible as it may seem to believe, writing the code in jQuery did *not* magically make the browser handle more simultaneous requests, nor tell me when the requests stopped blocking and started running. I know, right? Who'd have thought that jQuery shared the same limitations as plain JavaScript...